# Synchronous HTTP request from behind a proxy in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy

I use `http-sync` and `sync-request` for making synchronous http requests. Unfortunately, both these packages do not have support for making the request behind a proxy. Is there a way to make synchronous http requests behind a proxy server in node.js?

For Async http requests I use packages like http, https and request which support making requests behind proxy.

Comment: Not an answer: Just don't use these libraries, they're a bad idea.

Comment: @DougMoscrop why? Please drop few lines or links where this is explained.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/sync-request) library might help you out ... but the author leaves a disclaimer at the top of the repository that pretty much sums up why @DougMoscrop makes the claim that this is a bad idea.

Comment: While you're waiting for that HTTP response, *nothing else can happen* inside your JavaScript code. For a toy project you probably don't care, but it's just not worth not learning how to actually handle async control flow - the library `async` or just Promises are worth learning.